# Swift - UIButton with two lines of text

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I was wondering if it is possible to create a UIButton with two lines of text.  I need each line to have a different font size.  The first line will be 17 point and the second will be 11 point.  I've tried messing with putting two labels inside of a UIButton, but I can't get them to stay inside the bounds of the button.

I'm attempting to do all of this in the ui builder, and not programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 297, accepted):

There are two questions.

> I was wondering if it is possible to create a UIButton with two lines
>   of text

This is possible through using the storyboard or programmatically.

**Storyboard:**

Change the 'Line Break Mode' to **Character Wrap** or **Word Wrap** and use **Alt/Option + Enter** key to enter a new line in the UIButton's Title field.

[image]

**Programmatically:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        btnTwoLine?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
}
```

> I need each line to have a different font size
>   1

The worst case is, you can use a custom `UIButton` class and add two labels within it.

The better way is, make use of `NSMutableAttributedString`. Note that,this can be achieved through only programmatically.

**Swift 5:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnTwoLine: UIButton?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //applying the line break mode
    textResponseButton?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
    let buttonText: NSString = "hello\nthere"

    //getting the range to separate the button title strings
    let newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.range(of: "\n")

    //getting both substrings
    var substring1 = ""
    var substring2 = ""

    if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        substring1 = buttonText.substring(to: newlineRange.location)
        substring2 = buttonText.substring(from: newlineRange.location)
    }

    //assigning diffrent fonts to both substrings
    let font1: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17.0)!
    let attributes1 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font1]
    let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1, attributes: attributes1)

    let font2: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11.0)!
    let attributes2 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font2]
    let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring2, attributes: attributes2)

    //appending both attributed strings
    attrString1.append(attrString2)

    //assigning the resultant attributed strings to the button
    textResponseButton?.setAttributedTitle(attrString1, for: [])
}
```

**Older Swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnTwoLine: UIButton?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //applying the line break mode
        btnTwoLine?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;

        var buttonText: NSString = "hello\nthere"

        //getting the range to separate the button title strings
        var newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.rangeOfString("\n")

        //getting both substrings
        var substring1: NSString = ""
        var substring2: NSString = ""

        if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            substring1 = buttonText.substringToIndex(newlineRange.location)
            substring2 = buttonText.substringFromIndex(newlineRange.location)
        }

        //assigning diffrent fonts to both substrings
        let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17.0)
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: substring1 as String,
            attributes: NSDictionary(
                object: font!,
                forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])

        let font1:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11.0)
        let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: substring2 as String,
            attributes: NSDictionary(
                object: font1!,
                forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])

        //appending both attributed strings
        attrString.appendAttributedString(attrString1)

        //assigning the resultant attributed strings to the button
        btnTwoLine?.setAttributedTitle(attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Works great.  I am now wondering if there's any way to center the text on each line, and if there's any way to insert more space between the two lines.

Comment: you can align both line text to centre. write the following code  btnTwoLine?.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center or do it using the storyboard file(control section->Alignment)

Comment: may I know what is the purpose of putting more lines in between?

Comment: It depends on the size of the button.  If the button is big, then the two lines of text are going to be right in the middle, with a lot of space on the top and bottom.  That's not the look that I was going for.

Comment: yo have to apply some tricks here :) you can put more lines in between using multiple \n. I mean, "hello\n\n\nthere" will give you three spaces. however, don't forget to modify your code  var newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.rangeOfString("\n\n\n")

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, just to add you can two sizes of text set via the storyboard - see Musa Almatri's answer regarding text alignment below.  You can set the button title to Attributed instead of Plain, then you are able to set the alignment and font size of each line separately via the property inspector.

Comment: Thanks, man, your solution helped me, its character wrap, so at the end of the line, word don't complete. So I used word wrap from line break menu and my problem solved

Comment: Centre solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613394/884674

Answer (score 32):

I was looking for nearly the same topic, except that I don't need two different font sizes. In case someone is looking for a simple solution:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    button.setTitle("Foo\nBar", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonTapped), for: .allEvents)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Answer (score 17):

I have notice an issue in most of the solutions which is while making line break mode to "Character Wrap" the second line will be left aligned to the first line

To make all the lines centered.
just change the title From Plain to Attributed and then you can make each line centered

[image: attributed centered title]

Answer (score 8):

change line break to character wrap , select your button and in attribute inspector go to line break and change it to character wrap

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 3 Syntax**

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "First line\nSecond Line")
str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17), range: NSMakeRange(0, 10))
str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSMakeRange(11, 11))
button.setAttributedTitle(str, for: .normal)
```

Comment: not sure why, but I had to add button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: Didn't work in swift 4 first. Need to set "line break" to "word wrap" . Thanks man :)

Comment: original earlier answer is below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30679547/5318223

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this and my solution it was only in the Storyboard.

**Changes:**

It added in *Identity Inspector -> User Defined Runtime Attributes* (these KeyPaths):

- numberOfLines = 2
- titleLabel.textAlignment = 1

[User Defined Runtime Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZLmp.png)

I added this in attributes inspector:

- line break = word wrap

[Word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLa3h.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some of this in code. you can't set 2 different fonts in IB. In addition to changing the line break mode to character wrap, you need something like this to set the title,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "First line\nSecond Line")
        str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17), range: NSMakeRange(0, 10))
        str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), range: NSMakeRange(11, 11))
        button.setAttributedTitle(str, forState: .Normal)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**New with Xcode 13 (iOS 15)**

[image]

Starting with Xcode 13, the button's title and subtitle may have their attributes set separately.

***Using Storyboard:***

In the Attribute Inspector for the button, select "Attributed" by Title. Then change font size of the title and the subtitle.

[image]

***Or Programmatically:***

```
// Create Title
let titleSettings = AttributeContainer.font( UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Italic", size: 17)! )
yourButton.configuration?.attributedTitle = AttributedString("Button's Title", attributes: titleSettings)

// Create Subtitle
let subtitleSettings = AttributeContainer.font( UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Italic", size: 11)! )
yourButton.configuration?.attributedSubtitle = AttributedString("Button's Subtitle", attributes: subtitleSettings)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with labels, I guess.  I did this, and it seems to work ok.  I could create this as a UIButton and then expose the labels, I guess.  I don't know if this makes any sense.

```
    let firstLabel = UILabel()

    firstLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    firstLabel.text = "Hi"
    firstLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    firstLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, testButton.frame.height * 0.25, testButton.frame.width, testButton.frame.height * 0.2)
    testButton.addSubview(firstLabel)

    let secondLabel = UILabel()

    secondLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    secondLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    secondLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)
    secondLabel.text = "There"
    secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    secondLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, testButton.frame.height * 0.5, testButton.frame.width, testButton.frame.height * 0.2)
    testButton.addSubview(secondLabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solutions unfortunately did not work out for me when I wanted to have a mutliline button inside a CollectionView. Then a colleague showed me a workaround which I wanted to share in case someone has the same problem - hope this helps! Create a class which inherits from UIControl and extend it with a label, which will then behave similar like a button.

```
class MultilineButton: UIControl {

    let label: UILabel = {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.numberOfLines = 0
        $0.textAlignment = .center
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(isHighlighted ? 0.7 : 1.0)
            label.textColor = label.textColor.withAlphaComponent(isHighlighted ? 0.7 : 1.0)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my way:

```
func setButtonTitle(title: String, subtitle: String, button: UIButton){
        //applying the line break mode
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
        let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: Attributes.biggestLabel)
        let subtitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: subtitle, attributes: Attributes.label)
        let char = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: Attributes.biggestLabel)
        title.append(char)
        title.append(subtitle)
        button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }
```