# Swift -How to change the color of a UIButton's NSMutableAttributedString after it has been set

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsmutableattributedstring

I have 2 `UIButtons` and their `titles` and `colors` are initially set using `NSMutableAttributedString`. The text is [2 lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30680626/4833705)

I have a custom `UISegmentedControl` and when the segment is  switched I need to change only the color of the buttons. The way I do it now the colors do change but there is ugly blink when that occurs because the actual text gets set again. I need a smooth transition for the colors only

```
var selectedSegmentIndex = 0 {
    didSet {

        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.setTextForFollowersButton()
            self.setTextForFollowingButton()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I change only the color of the button's `NSMutableAttributedString`?**

Button Code:

```
var numOfFollowers = 0 {
    didSet {
        setTextForFollowersButton()
    }
}
var numOfFollowing = 0 {
    didSet {
        setTextForFollowingButton()
    }
}

lazy var followersButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
    // ...
    return button
}()

lazy var followingButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
    //...
    return button
}()

func setTextForFollowersButton() {

    let button = self.followersButton
    let buttonText = "Following\n\(String(numOfFollowing))" as NSString
    // other code for 2 lines of text

    var color = UIColor.blue

    if selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        color = UIColor.blue
    } else {
        color = UIColor.gray
    }

    let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1,
                                                attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font:
                                                    UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                             NSMutableAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])

    let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring2,
                                                attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font:
                                                    UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14),
                                                             NSMutableAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])

    attrString1.append(attrString2)
    button.setAttributedTitle(attrString1, for: [])
}

func setTextForFollowingButton() {

    let button = self.followingButton

    let buttonText = "Following\n\(String(numOfFollowing))" as NSString
    // other code for 2 lines of text

    var color = UIColor.blue

    if selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        color = UIColor.gray
    } else {
        color = UIColor.blue
    }

    let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1,
                                                attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font:
                                                    UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                                             NSMutableAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])

    let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring2,
                                                attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font:
                                                    UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14),
                                                             NSMutableAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])

    attrString1.append(attrString2)
    button.setAttributedTitle(attrString1, for: [])
}
```

Comment: Did you try to insert `UIView.animate` inside of `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` to make transition smoothly?

Comment: @LewWinczynski thanks, your answer worked. Please post it so I can accept it. I had to change the time to 0.05 for it to look better too.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Ok, will post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert `UIView.animate` function inside of `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` to make a smooth transition. Making any kind of animation of the UI asynchronously on the main thread is always recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this for a smooth transition without any blink at all is to use `UIView.performWithoutAnimation`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

        self.setTextForFollowersButton()
        self.setTextForFollowingButton()

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: @LewWinczynski here's another way to do it without animation