# Text alignment issue by programatically created buttons and View

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, text-alignment

I have a programtically created view inside that i have 8 buttons (3 button on one line).I have dynamic button title so my alignment gets messed up.
what i want is buttons on left center and right aligned if more text it should have 2 lines.

CreateBtn function creates the button
view width is 375 and height 130

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eAP3.png)

```
func CreateBtn() {
        
        let workingImage = UIImage(named: "WorkStatus") as UIImage?
        let workingButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -53, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        workingButton.setTitle("\(localWorking)", for: .normal)
        workingButton.setImage(workingImage, for: .normal)
        workingButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        workingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.WorkingbuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(workingButton)
        
        let idleImage = UIImage(named: "Idle") as UIImage?
        let idleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 58, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        idleButton.setTitle("\(localIdle)", for: .normal)
        idleButton.setImage(idleImage, for: .normal)
        
        idleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        idleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.IdlebuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(idleButton)
        
        let meetingImage = UIImage(named: "Meeting") as UIImage?
        let mettingButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 190, y: 0, width: 200, height: 60))
        mettingButton.setTitle("\(localMeeting)", for: .normal)
        mettingButton.setImage(meetingImage, for: .normal)
        mettingButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        mettingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.MeetingbuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(mettingButton)
        
        let lunchImage = UIImage(named: "Lunch") as UIImage?
        let lunchButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -60, y: 40, width: 200, height: 60))
        lunchButton.setTitle("\(localLunch)", for: .normal)
        lunchButton.setImage(lunchImage, for: .normal)
        lunchButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        lunchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.LunchbuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(lunchButton)
        
        let checkinImage = UIImage(named: "Check In") as UIImage?
        let checkinButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 75, y: 40, width: 200, height: 60))
        checkinButton.setTitle("\(localCheckin)", for: .normal)
        checkinButton.setImage(checkinImage, for: .normal)
        checkinButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        checkinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CheckInbuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(checkinButton)
        
        let checkoutImage = UIImage(named: "Check Out") as UIImage?
        let checkoutButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 198, y: 40, width: 200, height: 60))
        checkoutButton.setTitle("\(localCheckOut)", for: .normal)
        checkoutButton.setImage(checkoutImage, for: .normal)
        checkoutButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        checkoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CheckOutbuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(checkoutButton)
        
        let onMobileImage = UIImage(named: "On Mobile") as UIImage?
        let onMobileButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -45, y: 80, width: 200, height: 60))
        onMobileButton.setTitle("\(localOnMobile)", for: .normal)
        onMobileButton.setImage(onMobileImage, for: .normal)
        onMobileButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        onMobileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.OnMobilebuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(onMobileButton)
        
        let privateImage = UIImage(named: "Private Time") as UIImage?
        let privateButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 90, y: 80, width: 200, height: 60))
        privateButton.setTitle("\(localPrivateTime)", for: .normal)
        privateButton.setImage(privateImage, for: .normal)
        privateButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 93, green: 93, blue: 93), for: .normal)
        privateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.PrivateTimebuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(privateButton)
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by left-center and right-aligned however in order to make your text go in two lines you have to fix your button width( by setting wdth anchor ) and then setting the number of lines to two. This might prove helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679370/swift-uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text

Comment: use constraints please ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UIStackView`?
Here is a reference to Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

If you use stack views, you'll be able to align the buttons to top/bottom/left etc.

So, you put the first 3 items (let's say 'column') into a vertical stack view. And you repeat it on two more columns. Then you put all 3 columns into a horizontal stack view. This will help to easily align what you need. Don't forget to put width and height constraints before you put items into the stack views.

[image: Stack views hierachy]