# Title in button shrinks Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, programmatically-created

I have a button but when I add it to my view the text shrinks... I have no idea what is going on I think I've tried everything. Please help! Thanks!!

[image: Button]

This is how I'm creating my button

```
 private lazy var nextLessonButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Next Lesson", for: .normal)
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    return button
}()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - UIButton with two lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679370/swift-uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text)

Comment: I just realized my constraints were wrong... lol but thanks for the help mate!